# esp32 bluetooth + android

Tags: android, bluetooth, esp32

i'm trying to create an android app to send and receive data to ESP32 over Bluetooth and display it on lcd screen.
i found a code and use it [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66284486/send-data-from-android-phone-to-esp32?newreg=b98b7fd51d774eefb33966c07c57739f)

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MyBtEngine extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final int BT_STATE_NONE = 0;
    static final int BT_STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    static final int BT_STATE_CONNECTED = 2;
    //uid for all 3rd party devices (not android)
    private static final UUID UUID_BT_DEVICE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final String BT_DEVICE_MAC = "58:BF:25:8C:06:16";//put your device MAC !!!!


    private BtWaitConnThread   mWaitConnThread    = null;
    private BtWorkThread       mWorkThread        = null;
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mState;
    private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;


    MyBtEngine() {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        mState   =  BT_STATE_NONE;
    }
    synchronized void start(){
        if(mAdapter == null){  return; }
        BluetoothDevice device;
        try{
            device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BT_DEVICE_MAC);
        }
        catch (Exception e){  return; }

        if (mWaitConnThread != null) {mWaitConnThread.cancel(); mWaitConnThread = null;}
        if (mWorkThread != null) {    mWorkThread.cancel();     mWorkThread = null;}

        mWaitConnThread = new BtWaitConnThread(device);
        mWaitConnThread.start();
        setState(BT_STATE_CONNECTING);
    }
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (mWaitConnThread != null) { mWaitConnThread.cancel(); mWaitConnThread = null; }
        if (mWorkThread != null) {     mWorkThread.cancel();     mWorkThread = null; }
        setState(BT_STATE_NONE);
    }
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        Log.e("MyBtEngine", "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;
    }
    synchronized int getState() {  return mState; }
    public boolean writeBt(byte[] out) {
        BtWorkThread r; // temp obj , just to keep write function not to destroyed if mWorkThread finish
        synchronized (this) {
            if((mWorkThread == null)||(mState != BT_STATE_CONNECTED)){
                return false;
            }
            r = mWorkThread;
        }
        r.write(out);
        return true;
    }
    private synchronized void startWorker(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        bluetoothDevice = device;
        if (mWaitConnThread != null) {mWaitConnThread.cancel(); mWaitConnThread = null;}
        if (mWorkThread != null) {    mWorkThread.cancel(); mWorkThread = null;}
        mWorkThread = new BtWorkThread(socket);
        mWorkThread.start();
        setState(BT_STATE_CONNECTED);
    }



    private class BtWaitConnThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        private BtWaitConnThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID_BT_DEVICE);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        public void run() {

            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            try {
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) { }
                setState(BT_STATE_NONE);
                return;

            }

            synchronized (MyBtEngine.this) {
                mWaitConnThread = null;//set itself to null because thread exit soon
            }
            startWorker(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }
        private void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    private class BtWorkThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private BtWorkThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try {
                tmpIn  = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmInStream  = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {



            while (true) {
                try {
                    int charFromEsp = mmInStream.read();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    MyBtEngine.this.start();//restart from beginning
                    return; // exit worker thread
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            } catch (IOException e) { return false; }
            return true;
        }
        private void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

it work for sending data to ESP32 for me but the problem it won't connect, it need a manual connection
to bluetooth
the error message i get when i try to launch the app :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect()' on a nul object reference 
at com.exampe.myapplication.MyBtEngine$BtWaitConnThread.run(MyBtEngine.java:111)
```

Can anyone help me ??
thanks !

i'm expecting at least a connection request to bluetooth when i launch th app and when the bluetooth is disabled